# Multiple Definition Error in Compiler C++

Tags: c++, header

This is the image of my error.
[image: This is the image of my error.]

[This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8bab69373b011254675) is my header/cpp file.

`PCB.cpp`

```
#include "PCB.h"


PCB::PCB(){
    PID = 0;
    filename = " ";
    memStart = 0;
    cdrw = " ";
    filelength = 0;
}


PCB::PCB(int p, string fn, int m, string rw, int fl){
    PID = p;
    filename =  fn;
    memStart = m;
    cdrw = rw;
    filelength = fl;
}

void PCB::getParam(){
    cout << PID << " " << filename << "   " << memStart << " " << cdrw << " " << filelength << endl;
}

void PCB::setPID(int p){
    PID = p;
}

void PCB::setFile(string name){
    filename = name;
}

void PCB::setCDRW(string rw){
    cdrw = rw;
}

void PCB::setMem(int m){
    memStart = m;
}

void PCB::setLength(int l){
    filelength = l;
}

int PCB::returnPID(){
    return PID;
}

string PCB::returnFile(){
    return filename;
}

int PCB::returnMem(){
    return memStart;
}

string PCB::returnRW(){
    return cdrw;
}

int PCB::returnLength(){
    return filelength;
}
```

`PCB.h`

```
#ifndef PCB_H
#define PCB_H
#include<string>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

class PCB
{

    private:

        int PID;
        string filename;
        int memStart;
        string cdrw;
        int filelength;

    public:
        PCB();
        PCB(int, string, int, string, int);
        //setters
        void setPID(int);
        void setFile(string);
        void setMem (int);
        void setCDRW (string);
        void setLength (int);
        //getters
        void getParam();
        int returnPID();
        string returnFile();
        int returnMem();
        string returnRW();
        int returnLength();


};

#endif // PCB_H
```

I'm getting a Multiple Definition error and I have no idea why. Is it because I'm using namespace std or is it because of something else? I normally overload my constructors. I'm really confused.

Comment: You should post your code directly in this question instead of posting link to codes.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought there was too many lines to post and I didn't wanna bog it down.

Comment: and can you post main in the same time?

Comment: I added main() and it compiled right away so what task/function are trying to do?

Comment: While you're at it, **post the error text verbatim as well**. (and yes, unrelated, but using `using namespace std;` in header files [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You didn't include `PCB.cpp`  from `main.cpp`, did you?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/780cf536e3bdf619bebf This is my main.

Comment: MikeCAT got it, you have to include the `PCB.h` instead of `PCB.cpp`

Comment: Include PCB.h in my main.cpp or in my PCB.cpp? (Oh my god, it worked!)

Comment: In your main file, your main should always link to .h file .

Comment: ***Include PCB.h in my main.cpp or in my PCB.cpp?*** Both.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include"PCB.cpp"
```

is not a good way to use the program. You should replace the line with

```
#include "PCB.h"
```